# BottomNavigation navigate doesn't save the state

Tags: java, android, mvvm, navigation, bottomnavigationview

Hi I have an application which get bottom navigation menu items and data from server. but when I choose each item the data in other's lost and if I click on another item it's load again. but when I create a bottom navigation inside app and get data inside them from server with changing fragment data wont lost.

My Navigation Drawer:

```
private void setUpNavigationDrawer() {

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,
                binding.drawerLayout,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_close);

        binding.mainToolbar.setContentInsetStartWithNavigation(0);
        binding.drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder()
                .setOpenableLayout(binding.drawerLayout)
                .build();

        // Show and Manage the Drawer and Back Icon
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(
                this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration
        );
        binding.navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this::onDrawerMenuItemSelected);

        navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(this);
    }


    private void selectBottomNavigationItem(Bundle arguments) {
        Menu menus = binding.bottomNav.getMenu();
        currentPageLink = (String) arguments.get("link");
        for (int i = 0; i < menus.size(); i++) {
            if (bottomNavItemsDestinationMatches.get(i).equals(currentPageLink)) {
                menus.getItem(i).setChecked(true);
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    private boolean onBottomNavItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        String link = bottomNavItemsDestinationMatches.get(item.getItemId());

        if (Objects.equals(link, currentPageLink)) {
            return true;
        }

        navigateNormal(link, null);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestinationChanged(@NonNull NavController controller,
                                     @NonNull NavDestination destination, @Nullable Bundle arguments) {
        selectBottomNavigationItem(arguments);
        ((AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.app_bar)).setExpanded(true, true);
    }


    private boolean isTopLevelDestination() {
        try {
            NavBackStackEntry last = navController.getPreviousBackStackEntry();
            boolean isAtLast = last != null && ((FragmentNavigator.Destination) last.getDestination()).getClassName()
                    .equals(BaseFragment.class.getName());
            boolean isTopLevelDestination = currentPageLink != null && currentPageLink.replace("/", "")
                    .equalsIgnoreCase(defaultDestination.getLink().replace("/", ""));
            return isTopLevelDestination || isAtLast;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void navigateToTopLevelDestinationIfNotInBackStack() {
        for (int id : bottomNavItemsDestinationMatches.keySet()) {
            String link = bottomNavItemsDestinationMatches.get(id);
            if (Objects.equals(link, defaultDestination.getLink())) {
                binding.bottomNav.setSelectedItemId(id);
            }
        }

    }
```

Now my expample navigation.xml is:

```
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/base_fragment"
        android:name="com.poonehmedia.app.ui.base.BaseFragment">
        <argument
            android:name="args"
            app:argType="string"
            app:nullable="false" />
    </fragment>


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/home_fragment"
        android:name="com.poonehmedia.app.ui.home.HomeFragment">
        <argument
            android:name="address"
            app:argType="string"
            app:nullable="false" />
    </fragment>


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/profile_fragment"
        android:name="com.poonehmedia.app.ui.profile.ProfileFragment"
        android:label="">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_go_to_order"
            app:destination="@id/orders_fragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right" />
        <argument
            android:name="address"
            app:argType="string"
            app:nullable="false" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
```

so when I click on a bottomNavigation Item finally this function called:

```
private void navigateNormal(String link, Runnable onSuccessOptional) {
    navigator.navigate(this,
            link,
            state -> {
                if (state instanceof NavigationState.Loading) {
                    navProgress(true);
                } else if (state instanceof NavigationState.Error) {
                    navProgress(false);
                } else if (state instanceof NavigationState.Success) {
                    navProgress(false);
                    if (onSuccessOptional != null) {
                        onSuccessOptional.run();
                    }
                }
            }
    );
}
```

and my navigator.navigate is:

```
 public void navigate(FragmentActivity activity, String link, INavigationState state) {
    try {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(activity, R.id.main_nav_fragment);
        getDataAndNavigate(navController, link, null, false, false, state);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.error(TAG, "Could not Naviate: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

and getDataAndNavigate function is:

```
 private void getDataAndNavigate(NavController controller, String link, JsonObject postBody,
                                boolean isPost, boolean isPop, INavigationState state) {
    try {
        if (link == null || link.isEmpty()) {
            state.onNext(new NavigationState.Error(context.getString(R.string.error_navigating)));
            return;
        }

        // support full path links
        NavigationUrl navigationUrl = resolveLink(link);

        if (navigationUrl.isExternal()) {
            openUrl(navigationUrl.getLink());
            return;
        }

        Single<Response<CommonResponse<Object>>> request = resolveRequest(navigationUrl, postBody, isPost);

        // start showing progress
        state.onNext(new NavigationState.Loading());

        // resolve url
        disposable = request
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(response -> {
                    dataController.onSuccess(response);


                    NavigationArgs navigationArgs = extractCurrentAction(
                            response.body(),
                            navigationUrl.getLink()

                    );


                    if (navigateTo(controller, navigationArgs, isPop)) {
                        state.onNext(new NavigationState.Success(navigationArgs));
                    } else {
                        state.onNext(new NavigationState.Error(context.getString(R.string.error_navigating)));
                    }

                }, throwable -> {
                    dataController.onFailure(throwable);
                    state.onNext(new NavigationState.Error(context.getString(R.string.error_navigating)));
                });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.error(TAG, e.getMessage());
        ACRA.getErrorReporter().handleException(new CrashReportException(
                "An error occurred while fetching next destination data in (NavigationHelper). ", e));
    }
}
```

I tried above code ... I expect that all bottom navigation item's state's saved and on navigation their state wont lost and no need to get data from server again. but each time I navigate to a item it should download data again